# Why does my application.properties are overwritten by external

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two java projects, one is spring boot application, which starts application server. This project has dependency to my-utils.jar, which has its own `application.properties`.
And whenever I try to run my web application/tests there. It seems to be fetching `application.properties` not from web application but instead from jar file.

I have run debug and did some checks in `PropertiesPropertySourceLoader` and I was able to confirm it that it nevers load my properties. There are loaded only `application.properties` from jar and `application-dev.properties` if profile is set. Is it default behaviour for spring boot?

I am using java 17, and spring boot 3+

Comment: Could you try to remove the properties file from third-party jar and check that the properties file is loaded inside main project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name implies `application.properties` should be used for the application, not for a library.  Spring Boot searches for `application.properties` [in the classpath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files) and both files are in the classpath, so it takes the first one it finds.  Just rename the file in the library to `my-utils.properties` or, if the library uses Spring, use `@Value` annotations and put all config params in the `application.properties` of the application; in this case you can merge the two properties files phisically (deleting the one in the library) or logically (with `--spring.config.location` or [`spring.config.import`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing), note that for logical merge you have to rename the file of the library).

Answer (score 2):

That's standard behavior.
Spring Applications choose their own applications.properties, unless you declare a specific one.

While you start your web application, you can declare this parameter:

```
--spring.config.location=/your/location/to/application.properties
```

Full example:

```
java --spring.config.location=/data/spring-applications/application.properties -jar my_java_project.jar
```